# Can't change TableView size

Tags: xcode, uitableview, frame

In my.m file:

```
@synthesize ListLearnTab;
...........
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ListLearnTab.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416);

    }
```

where ListLearnTab I declared in .h as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *ListLearnTab;
```

I spend many hours and don't know why TableView doesn't want resize. I put this ListLearnTab.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416); in many places, but TableView stay as I declare in Xcode (manualy).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think. I set the size of the table in the code, like you. I could see it on the story board. The prototype cell looked correct, but only seemed to go halfway across the table when the app ran. I dragged the entire view controller out bigger on the storyboard, clicked on the view itself and dragged it out, then clicked on the table and did the same. If I recall, I changed the widths of everything in the inspector to make them larger than the frame specification in viewDidLoad.
I got everything working. Sorry about not remembering the exact step that solved the problem. 
If that's the same as your trouble, how this helps! -Rob